# Please put more love into close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Whenever we close questions we feel to be off topic we can choose **other** for a custom wording:

[image]

Choose short but meaningful words to help the OP to improve their question.

Dots only as shown above will not help anybody. Please do not blindly approve such a close reason when reviewing (this had sadly happened here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today the closing reasons improved considerably. People added meaningful "other" close reasons to off topic questions. This is great!